# consumer producer code undeclared errors linux debug

Tags: c, linux, debugging, unix, buffer

Trying to compile my code in linux by doing gcc -o consumer.c -lpthread -lm and I am getting compile errors about having undeclared for things I, to the best of my knowledge, have declared. Most of the undeclared seem to be related to buffers, of which this is my first program using buffers. Here are the errors (edited to reflect changes)

```
typedef char buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // asm or __attribute__ before "buffer"

both of these(expected ')' before 'item'
int insert_item(buffer_item item)
int insert_item(buffer_item item)


int remove_item(buffer_item *item)  //expected ')' before * token
```

and here is my full code after the changes

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define RAND_DIVISOR 100000000
#define TRUE 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000


pthread_mutex_t mutex; //mutex lock
sem_t full, empty; //semaphores
typedef char buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int counter; //buffer counter

pthread_t tid1, tid2;       //Thread ID
pthread_attr_t attr; // thread attributes

void *producer(void *param); // producer thread
void *consumer(void *param); //consumer thread

void initializeData() {

   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); //Create mutex lock
   sem_init(&full, 0, 0);  // Create the full semaphore and initialize to 0
   sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); // Create the empty semaphore and initialize to BUFFER_SIZE
   pthread_attr_init(&attr); //default attributes
   counter = 0;
}

// Producer Thread
int insert_item(buffer_item item)
void *producer(void *param) {

   while(TRUE) {
      // random sleep time
      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
      sleep(rNum);
     int item = rand()%100; // item is a random number between 1-100
      sem_wait(&empty); //get empty lock
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //get mutex lock

      if(insert_item(item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, " Producer report error condition\n");
      }
      else {
         printf("producer produced %d\n", item);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); //release mutex lock
      sem_post(&full); //signal full
   }
}

// Consumer Thread
void *consumer(void *param) {

   while(TRUE) {
      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR; // sleep for a random period of time
      sleep(rNum);
      int item = rand()%100; // item is a random number between 1-100
      sem_wait(&full);// aquire the full lock */
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);// aquire the mutex lock
      if(remove_item(&item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Consumer report error condition\n");
      }
      else {
         printf("consumer consumed %d\n", item);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);// release mutex lock
      sem_post(&empty); //signal empty
   }
}

int insert_item(buffer_item item)
{
   // add item as long as buffer isn't full
   if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
      buffer[counter] = item;
      counter++;
      return 0;
   }
   else {
      return -1; //buffer full error
   }
}

// Remove an item from the buffer
int remove_item(buffer_item *item)// remove item and decrement counter when buffer not empty
{
   if(counter > 0) {
      *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
      counter--;
      return 0;
   }
   else { //buffer empty error
   }
      return -1;
   }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int i; //loop counter
   if(argc != 4) {
      fprintf(stderr, "USAGE:./main.out <INT> <INT> <INT>\n");
   }
   int mainSleepTime = atoi(argv[1]); // sleep time in seconds
   int numProd = atoi(argv[2]); // producer threads
   int numCons = atoi(argv[3]); // consumer threads

   initializeData(); //initialize app

   for(i = 0; i < numProd; i++) {
      pthread_create(&tid1,&attr,producer,NULL);
    }

   for(i = 0; i < numCons; i++) {
      pthread_create(&tid2,&attr,consumer,NULL);
   }

   // sleep in milliseconds
   //sleep(mainSleepTime);

   pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
   pthread_join(tid2, NULL);

   printf("Program Exiting\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

Edit: latest code and screenshot of errors http://tinypic.com/r/xptzww/9

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define RAND_DIVISOR 100000000
#define TRUE 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000


pthread_mutex_t mutex; //mutex lock
sem_t full, empty; //semaphores
typedef char buffer_item;
int counter; //buffer counter

pthread_t tid1, tid2;       //Thread ID
pthread_attr_t attr; // thread attributes

void *producer(void *param); // producer thread
void *consumer(void *param); //consumer thread

void initializeData() {

   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); //Create mutex lock
   sem_init(&full, 0, 0);  // Create the full semaphore and initialize to 0
   sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); // Create the empty semaphore and initialize to BUFFER_SIZE
   pthread_attr_init(&attr); //default attributes
   counter = 0;
}

// Producer Thread
int insert_item(buffer_item item)
void *producer(void *param) {

   while(TRUE) {
      // random sleep time
      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
      sleep(rNum);
     int item = rand()%100; // item is a random number between 1-100
      sem_wait(&empty); //get empty lock
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //get mutex lock

      if(insert_item(item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, " Producer report error condition\n");
      }
      else {
         printf("producer produced %d\n", item);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); //release mutex lock
      sem_post(&full); //signal full
   }
}

// Consumer Thread
void *consumer(void *param) {

   while(TRUE) {
      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR; // sleep for a random period of time
      sleep(rNum);
      int item = rand()%100; // item is a random number between 1-100
      sem_wait(&full);// aquire the full lock */
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);// aquire the mutex lock
      if(remove_item(&item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Consumer report error condition\n");
      }
      else {
         printf("consumer consumed %d\n", item);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);// release mutex lock
      sem_post(&empty); //signal empty
   }
}

int insert_item(buffer_item item){// add item as long as buffer isn't full
   if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
      buffer[counter] = item;
      counter++;
      return 0;
   }
   else {
      return -1; //buffer full error
   }
}

// Remove an item from the buffer
int remove_item(buffer_item *item)// remove item and decrement counter when buffer not empty
{
   if(counter > 0) {
      *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
      counter--;
      return 0;
   }
   else { //buffer empty error
   }
      return -1;
   }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int i; //loop counter
   if(argc != 4) {
      fprintf(stderr, "USAGE:./main.out <INT> <INT> <INT>\n");
   }
   int mainSleepTime = atoi(argv[1]); // sleep time in seconds
   int numProd = atoi(argv[2]); // producer threads
   int numCons = atoi(argv[3]); // consumer threads

   initializeData(); //initialize app

   for(i = 0; i < numProd; i++) {
      pthread_create(&tid1,&attr,producer,NULL);
    }

   for(i = 0; i < numCons; i++) {
      pthread_create(&tid2,&attr,consumer,NULL);
   }

   // sleep in milliseconds
   //sleep(mainSleepTime);

   pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
   pthread_join(tid2, NULL);

   printf("Program Exiting\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What is it `buffer_item`? Maybe you want just `char` without `buffer_item`: `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; ... char item;`

Comment: Is this the complete code? You declare `char BUFFER_SIZE;` without value and just after `char buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];` → what is its size? Whatever in this "complete code" what is `buffer_item`? It is declared later. Compiler reads data as human, from top to down.

Comment: I'm not sure what size to make buffer size and as for the buffer items I looked at code from other sources where they were doing buffer items as well.

Comment: Whatever the main problem of your code is that you rely on global values (declaring/initialising them afterward). You should avoid that kind of things and declare variables inside functions (like main) and pass them as parameters to your functions.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared but not defined BUFFER_SIZE.
Instead

```
   char BUFFER_SIZE;
```

try

```
   char BUFFER_SIZE = some_value;
```

where some_value should be anything  between 1-255

Line:

```
   char buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

should be:

```
   char buffer_item[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Comment: ahh I see I thought buffer size without a value would just dynamically expand, kind of like how you can expand the size of an array when you read in a file

Comment: what about the "item" problem?

Comment: added solution for item problem

Comment: thanks I decided to do a define for the buffer size though

Comment: yes, define here is better since you do not change the BUFFER_SIZE, I have suggested with char as you had this declared already

Answer (score 2):

A variable declaration should look like:

```
<type name> <variable name>;
```

There is no standard type `buffer_item`. If you want to use custom type name it can be defined:

```
typedef char buffer_item;
```

I assume that you wanted to use `char` for that type, since `item` should keep numbers from `0` to `99` and the `char` type is enough for that.
After that line the name `buffer_item` is alias for `char`. So variables can be declared as `buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];` or `buffer_item item;`.
In that case lines like `char buffer_item;` are redundant. Also you do not need to write `char` before `buffer_item`, since `buffer_item` is already another name for `char`, so `char buffer_item;` is the same as `char char;` that does not make any sense.

Probably that the unknow symbol `BUFFER_SIZE` should defined as you define `#define RAND_DIVISOR 100000000`. Typically capital letters in names in C are used for macro definitions. So, you may want to set that size on the top of your file, for example:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
```

In that case the line `char BUFFER_SIZE;` is not needed anymore.

You use function `insert_item` before its declaration. So, to compile that you may put forward declaration also on top before `producer()`:

```
int insert_item(buffer_item item);
```

That should be enough to compile the code.

---

*Updated for new errors*

Type declaration uses special keyword `typedef` to create type alias. Here to declare that `buffer_item` name is used as a type name and it is the same as `char` it should be exactly:

```
typedef char buffer_item;
```

The buffer array should be defined below as:

```
buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Forward function declaration requires semicolon at the end:

```
int insert_item(buffer_item item);
```

I'm not sure that it will work as expected, but now it should be compiled.