# buffer is being read as undeclared in program even though it is

Tags: c, linux, debugging, consumer, producer

Trying to sort out some errors from another of my questions. My compiler is reading buff[counter] as buffer and thus undeclaring it. The buffer was given to me as part of the starting code, so I'm not sure what buffer[counter] means. Trying to google it doesn't help since I don't know how to find out the meaning of buffer[counter] is it like buffer_counter? Are they saying buffer_counter is the buffers' counter? any help would be appreciated, especially if someone could explain the [counter] part, because then I could fix it myself.

I have this at the start of my code

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int insert_item(buffer_item item){// add item as long as buffer isn't full
   if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
      buffer[counter] = item;
      counter++;
      return 0;
   }
   else {
      return -1; //buffer full error
   }
}

// Remove an item from the buffer
int remove_item(buffer_item *item)// remove item and decrement counter when buffer not empty
{
   if(counter > 0) {
      *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
      counter--;
      return 0;
   }
   else { //buffer empty error
   }
      return -1;
   }
```

Also this if(remove_item(&item)) {

triggers a related erorr called "passing argument 1 of remove_item from incompatible pointer type" as seen here

```
void *consumer(void *param) {

   while(TRUE) {
      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR; // sleep for a random period of time
      sleep(rNum);
      int item = rand()%100; // item is a random number between 1-100
      sem_wait(&full);// aquire the full lock */
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);// aquire the mutex lock
      if(remove_item(&item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Consumer report error condition\n");
      }
      else {
         printf("consumer consumed %d\n", item);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);// release mutex lock
      sem_post(&empty); //signal empty
   }
}
```

Comment: `buffer` is an array, `buffer[counter]` access the element of the array with index `counter`. Since neither of these variables is declared in your function, they must be global variables.

Comment: so I need to do buffer[counter] = 0; at the start of my program (where I define global variables)?

Comment: You can't google `buffer_item` because it's not a standard C type. It should be declared somewhere in the program in a `typedef`.

Comment: You don't need to do that. Just initialize `counter = 0;`. That happens automatically for global variables.

Comment: oh I misunderstood then but even if I do that it still just think buffer[counter] means a variable called buffer

Comment: What do you mean by "compiler is reading buff[counter] as buffer"? Where is `buff[counter]` in the code?

Comment: That's what I said -- `buffer[counter]` means that `buffer` is either an array variable or a pointer variable, and `counter` is an index into the array.

Comment: This is really basic C syntax. I think you need to go back to the textbooks and study the language.

Comment: hmmm I think it's because this is a buffer that I'm not sure of. I thought buffer was a special array I mean if I had myarray[index] it would be clear to me but for this it's not. so if I did " int buffer[counter] = {o}; "would that work or do I need to say int buffer = 0; int counter=o;?

Comment: Global variables are automatically initialized to 0 by default. Global arrays have all their elements initialized to 0.

Comment: any idea on how to fix it though? Nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: Where are the definitions of `buffer` and `counter`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the global `buffer` and `counter` variables:

```
typedef char buffer_item;

buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
unsigned int counter;
```

Comment: is buffer type like int buffer?  int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

Comment: I've updated the answer. It seems like all these things should already have been declared in the code you received. Could you have forgotten a `#include` line that loads the header file that declares them?

Comment: Didn't post the full code here I do in my previous one though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621513/buffer-is-being-read-as-undeclared-in-program-even-though-it-is

Comment: That's this question. I think you meant to link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599060/consumer-producer-code-undeclared-errors-linux-debug

Comment: If you've made the fixes from that other question, you shouldn't be getting an error about `buffer` being undeclared.

Comment: exactly that's why I'm so confused